# SQL Server conversion failed due to outer WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Don't ask me why I'm doing this or what problem I try to solve. Due to circumstances with multiple parties etc we bumped into this error - which I think might be a bug in SQL Server. Please don't offer me alternative solutions, I'm only trying to understand why this particular case fails.

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE T (Id NVARCHAR(50))
```

With these entries:

```
INSERT INTO T(Id) VALUES
    (NULL),
    ('45B7522C-248E-48A9-92B2-BC164C5F58EC'),
    ('usr://fed/45B7522C-248E-48A9-92B2-BC164C5F58EC')
```

I have a view/subquery on this table (both give the same result):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, Id) AS Id_Converted
    FROM T
    WHERE Id LIKE '________-____-____-____-____________'
) V
WHERE Id_Converted = '45B7522C-248E-48A9-92B2-BC164C5F58EC'
```

This fails with the message:

```
Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
```

I would expect that the inner `WHERE` (selecting only the records that *can* be converted to a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`) is used before the `CONVERT` statement followed by the outer `WHERE`. I know that SQL Server will first get the matching records using the WHERE-statements, but in this case the outer WHERE shouldn't be used unless the Id field is converted to `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`.
Without this outer `WHERE` statement, the subquery works fine.

Any thoughts on this?

For those interested, a workaround could be using this SELECT statement:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN Id LIKE '________-____-____-____-____________'
        THEN CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, Id) 
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Id_Converted
```

Comment: `usr://fed/45B7522C-248E-48A9-92B2-BC164C5F58EC` this is not UNIQUEIDENTIFIER so it will not convert

Comment: Yes I know, that's why that innere WHERE is there. It will only select those records that cán convert. This issue is about the outer WHERE, please read the question entirely please :)

Comment: [SQL Server should not raise illogical errors](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) on Connect. Of course, there's no sign that they're planning to ever fix this. It's been open since 2010.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the query optimiser collapses the subquery and outer query into a single table scan with the following condition:

```
CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,T.Id,0)={guid'45B7522C-248E-48A9-92B2-BC164C5F58EC'} AND T.Id like N'________-____-____-____-____________'
```

(you can see this by displaying the execution plan).  The best I could do to prevent the query optimiser doing this is to make the subquery a (indexed, schemabound) view which then allows the use of the `NOEXPAND` table hint:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.V
with schemabinding
AS
    SELECT CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, Id) AS Id_Converted
    FROM dbo.T
    WHERE Id LIKE '________-____-____-____-____________';
GO

create unique clustered index V_idx1 on V (Id_Converted);
GO

SELECT * FROM  V with (noexpand)
WHERE Id_Converted = '45B7522C-248E-48A9-92B2-BC164C5F58EC'
```

But you may prefer your workaround!

Comment: Of course, the query optimizer *shouldn't* rearrange the query and produce this error since SQL has a logical processing order and optimizers should only rearrange operations provided they still produce the same results as they *would* have produced if they'd followed the logical processing order. Link to a Connect item about this provided in comment below question.

Comment: I agree. We also considered making the view schemabound, but the situation is like this. Company A has ownership of the table, company B has ownership of the view, and we are company C, but everything will run on a server in ownership of A. In short, we rather not touch the underlying table and view. But is works like you said. But SQL Server just shouldn't do this...